# Function is calculating wrong, return 0 instead of 500k, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I fix this?

```
pricec = {
    "Case" : 56950,
    "PSU" : 48950,
    "Mobo" : 59500,
    "GPU" : 124990,
    "Memory" : 57800,
    "CPU" : 53900,
    "SSD" : 99900,
    "Cooling" : 0
}

total = 0

def pricet(total, pricec):
    for x in pricec:
        total += pricec[x]
        return total
pricet(total, pricec)

print ("Build Cost: " + str(total)+"kr")
```

Answer (score 5):

You aren't setting the total variable from the return value of the `pricet()` function.

```
pricec = {
    "Case" : 56950,
    "PSU" : 48950,
    "Mobo" : 59500,
    "GPU" : 124990,
    "Memory" : 57800,
    "CPU" : 53900,
    "SSD" : 99900,
    "Cooling" : 0
}

def pricet(pricec):
    total = 0
    for x in pricec:
        total += pricec[x]
    return total

total = pricet(pricec)

print("Build Cost: " + str(total) + "k")
```

Also, there is a much simpler way to sum the values of a dictionary than looping:

```
def pricet(pricec):
    return sum(pricec.values())
```